# Gradle package's Java version is being read as a different version

Tags: java, gradle

I have a project that is classes I extend in many projects at work.

I packaged the project and published it to a maven repo on gitlab. The issue is when I try to import it in another project, it is being read by Gradle as Java 11 while the project I'm importing into is Java 8.

The issue is, I define this in the gradle.build of both projects:

```
java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

When I try to import it in another project:

```
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.saifxhatem:my-package:1.0.
     Required by:
         project :
      > No matching variant of com.saifxhatem:my-package:1.0 was found. The consumer was configured to find an API of a library compatible with Java 8, preferably in the form of class files, and its dependencies declared externally but:
          - Variant 'apiElements' capability com.saifxhatem:my-package:1.0 declares an API of a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component compatible with Java 8
          - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability com.saifxhatem:my-package:1.0 declares a runtime of a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component compatible with Java 8
```

Comment: What Java version does your built project declare? 11? Then the error makes perfect sense. If that's not the case, can you [edit] the question and add a [mcve]?

Comment: I was under the impression that this part in gradle:
`sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8`
`targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8`

Was how I defined my project's version. I'm not sure how to give a reproducible example since this is the exact error that happens. 

I also noticed some weird behaviour - when I publish the package, if the version was `1.0` then this error would occur, but if I set it to `0.1.0` then it works fine. Both the gradle file and the source code do not change, the only change is the version number.

Comment: Because you said you defined the compatibility in your parent project. Maybe you forgot to build with this settings.
Had this issue as well but in my project there was an other place where the java version was externalized in an other configuration file.